# Yii console with different configs

Tags: php, yii, console

In the web application we use same code and modules with different configs like:

in index.php file app will decide, wchin config to turn:

```php
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']){
    default:
        $yii=$webRoot.'/framework/yiilite.php';
        $config = $webRoot.'/protected/config/main.php';
    break;
        case 'someurl.com':
              ...
        break;
        ...
}
```

But, how can I do it with console application?
The reason in that I use different databases ant etc.

is it possible to do something like this:

```
$ ./protected/yiic --application=myappname [all defined commands as default]
```

in the code a

```
--application
```

will set with which console config to work

**more explanation**

my answer to @Joe Miller
But the problem is, how choose theme?
I did in the files foloowings:

in protectes/yiic

```
$__appId = null;
for( $__i=1,$__max=count($argv); $__i<$__max; ++$__i ) {
    if ( strpos($argv[$__i],'--appid',0) === 0 ) {
        $__appId = substr($argv[$__i], 8);
        unset($argv[$__i]);
    }
}

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/yiic.php');
```

and in protected/yiic.php

```
$__appIdsList = array(
    'my_site_1',
    'my_site_2',
    'my_site_3',
    'my_site_4',
);

$yiic=dirname(__FILE__).'/../framework/yiic.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/console_'.$__appId.'.php';

require_once($yiic);
```

and it works and it catchs that config file what I need

```
./protected/yiic --appid=my_site_1
```

bu when I`m trying to do migrate

```
./protected/yiic --appid=my_site_1 migrate
```

the app cant recognize comman and gives me migrates help list

**And final conslusion (I solved it)**

I`d like to add transperent console command without affecting it to other execution of builtin console commands and custom console commands.

Another requirement is, solve this issue on a low-level approach, without inheritance or overloading other classes or methods.

So, my solution is:

in protected/yiic

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$__appId = null;
for( $__i=1,$__max=count($argv); $__i<$__max; ++$__i ) {
    if ( strpos($argv[$__i],'--appid',0) === 0 ) {
        $__appId = substr($argv[$__i], 8);
        unset($argv[$__i]);
        unset($_SERVER['argv'][$__i]);
        $argv = $_SERVER['argv'] = array_values($argv);
    }
}

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/yiic.php');
```

and in /protected/yiic.php

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$__appIdsList = array(
    'app_1',
    'app_2',
);

$yiic=dirname(__FILE__).'/../framework/yiic.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/console_'.$__appId.'.php';

if ( !is_file($config) ) {
    die("Error: There is no or wrong parametr appid. Please set parametr or correct. Example -appid={application_name}\n\tThe list of available appid:\n\t\t - ".implode("\n\t\t - ", $__appIdsList));
}

require_once($yiic);
```

and now it is possible to set param "appid" in any place of command line, like

```
./protected/yiic  migrate --appid=app_1
```

and it acts only in that app what we need

PS: in any case, thanks @Joe Miller

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, that was really interesting. I'm going to investigate doing this kind of stuff with my own Yii now :-)

Comment: After your investigation, please, share it with us;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I founded more confortable solution!
It`s more easy, and solved all my requirements.

in the file

```
protected/yiic.php
```

I write:

```
...
$yiic=dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/framework/yiic.php';

if ( strpos(__FILE__,{first/place}) !== false ) {
    $config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/first_config.php';
} elseif ( strpos(__FILE__,{second/place}) !== false ) {
    $config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/second_plase.php';
} else {
    // by default
    $config=dirname(__FILE__).'/config/console.php'; 
}
require_once($yiic);
...
```

where **{first/place}**,**{second/place}** - a part of the project`s path. For example:

Your first project is placed in:

```
/var/www/aproject/first_one
```

and the second one on the

```
/var/www/aproject/second_one
```

than you checks will be:

```
// for first porject
strpos(__FILE__,'aproject/first_one') !== false
```

and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Copy yiic.php for example to cron.php and modify the config file in the cron.php

then use as if it were yiic, for example:

```
  cd ~/protected;php ~/protected/cron.php app command --param=value >> ~/runtime/crontab.log
```

Comment: and if i`ve got 10 or 20 apps I have to create a lot of "crop.php" files? like
    cron_[app_name].php

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're trying to do correctly, I think you might need something like this. I've referred to this article http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console#creating-commands. I've not tried this, so I'm just interpreting the article.

Create a base command class, from which you will extend all the other commands. The base class run() method selects the config file to load.

In protected>commands you need a file migrate.php. This must contain the class MigrateCommand, and must extend CConsoleCommand. You can then override the run() method of this class to allow parameters to be passed to the method. e.g.

In protected>commands>baseCommand.php

```
class MyBaseCommand extends CConsoleCommand{
        public function run($args){
            //Code here to select the config file to load
            //$args are any arguments you have passed in the command line
        }
    }
```

In protected>commands>migrate.php

```
class Migrate extends MyBaseCommand{
    public function run($args){
        parent::run($args);
        //Do your own stuff here
    }
}
```

you should then be able to call the command as;

```
./protected/yiic migrate --appid=my_site_1
```

Note that the name of the command appears first, I'm not sure if this is important, but it's what the guide says! I hope I've understood your question this time!

Comment: came close but not very.
I need all default commands work properly via console, like
- message
- migrate 
- shell
- webapp
and others
but with different config files at all

Comment: Hmm, really interesting question. I wonder if you could use inheritance to define a base Command class which will select the config file to use, then your other commands can do what they need to do. I've edited my answer to a suggested solution. If this isn't close, I'll have to bow out as not qualified to answer!

Comment: thanks @Joe. But I found other solution. check out my question)